# Can access @conn in json view template?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have some variables in conn.assigns and I am trying to get access to these variables via @conn in a json view render.
Is this even possible?

```
 def render("show.json", %{blog: blog}) do
   # @conn <-- ?
   %{data: render_one(newsfeed, Api.BlogView, "blog.json")}
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried passing these as params to the view? E.g. in your controller

> data = %{param1: Conn.assigns[:example], blog: blog}
>
> render ExampleView, "show.json", data: data

Then in your view:

```
 def render("show.json", %{data: %{param1: param, blog: blog}}) do
   param #...do something 
   %{data: render_one(newsfeed, Api.BlogView, "blog.json")}
 end
```